# Sort ArrayList by Date in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of Product objects by their `useby` Dates, but some of the objects may have their `Date useby = null`

What I want to do is sort the list by "useby" Dates, and put all the Objects that has `Date useby = null` on the bottom or on the top of the list.

```
public static void sort() {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Product>() {
            public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
                if (o1.getUseDate() == null || o2.getUseDate() == null) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return o1.getUseDate().compareTo(o2.getUseDate());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my code and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if (o1.getUseDate() == null || o2.getUseDate() == null)`. Here you are checking if either of the two `Product`'s has a null date. If even one of them does the return result of `0` means that the `Comparator` will see them as equal. Even if just one of them has a null date. Here you probably want to do some more in-depth checking. The following code will result in `Product`'s with `null` Dates being put at the start.

```
if(o1.getUseDate() == null && o2.getUseDate() == null)
    return 0; //They are both null, both equal
if(o1.getUseDate() == null && o2.getUseDate() != null)
    return -1; // The first is null and the second is not, return the first as lower than the second
if(o1.getUseDate() != null && o2.getUseDate() == null)
    return 1; //The first is not null and the second is, return the first as higher than the second
else
    return o1.getUseDate().compare(o2.getUseDate()); //Return the actual comparison
```

This is obviously a little verbose, but it should give you an idea as to what you should actually be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`return 0;` means that compared elements are equal (in other words you shouldn't swap them).

In case of `null`s consider

- returning `0` if both values are `null` (first value is same as second value - don't swap)
- returning `-1` if first value is `null` but second is not null (first element is lesser than second - don't swap)
- returning `1` if second value is `null` and first is not null (first element is greater than second - swap them)

Answer (score 1):

From `compare` javadoc:

> Compares its two arguments for order.  Returns a negative integer,
>       zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>       to, or greater than the second.

But from this line of your code:

```
if (o1.getUseDate() == null || o2.getUseDate() == null) {
   return 0;
```

we can see that you're practically telling the comparator to consider useDates as being equal when at least one of them is `null`, and this is not what you want.

Since null means "nothing", it's quite weird to compare the concept of nothing with a date, but if you want to allow null values, then you have to handle this situation properly, resulting into a more vorbose code:

```
if(o1.getUseDate() == null){
    return o2.getUseDate() == null ? 0 : -1; //or +1 if you want null values at the bottom of your list
}
if(o2.getUseDate() == null){
    return o1.getUseDate() == null ? 0 : -1; // or +1 ...
}
return o1.getUseDate().compare(o2.getUseDate()); // 2 non null dates, do a real comparison
```